# dom to xml not storing data properly mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Having issue with dom to xml transformer..
I got response from microsoft connector and transform into xml format and store xml data into file.
But the problem is its not storing in proper way..In single line it store all the data.
How to solve this ptblem?

Below is flow

```
 <flow name="flow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>

        <dynamicsax:invoke-document-service-operation config-ref="Microsoft" serviceAndSoapActionUri="XXXXX" doc:name="Microsoft"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="test" outputPattern="test.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
```

I want to store  in proper xml format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably explore xmlprettyprinter-transformer of mule.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/xmlprettyprinter-transformer

Regards,
Ralph